# Devise's `#sign_in_and_redirect` persists the user and even if invalid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth

Using the Omniauth Github strategy with Devise with Rails 4.

I have a failed validation which causes the #create in the code below to fail (which returns the failed User object and enters the `if` since it still evaluates to `true`) and the not-persisted user is then passed to `#sign_in_and_redirect` (with model errors intact).  I am comfortable with everything up until here.  Bad code, but bad in ways that make sense.

Despite this, the user is **actually created** somewhere in the `#sign_in_and_redirect` code (discovered by narrowing it down with descriptive `puts`'s and server logs).

A) I can't find where in the Devise or Omniauth source this is occurring.  I couldn't find a `#save` or `#create` call.

B) Even if `#create` or `#save` were being called by `#sign_in_and_redirect`, they should still fail due to the errors.

How is this possible?!

```
class OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
...
user = User.create(provider: omniauth['provider'], 
    uid: omniauth['uid'], 
    email: omniauth['info']['email'], 
    username: omniauth['info']['nickname'])
if user
  flash.now[:notice] = "Signed in successfully"

  # Makes perfect sense how we got here, user is currently not persisted
  sign_in_and_redirect(:user, user)
  # Somehow, magically, user is now persisted

else
...
```

Answer (score 0):

In the given code though the user is not getting creating due to the validation error, but still `user` will not be `false`. It will actually be a user object object with the validation errors. So, if you would like to check add a condition of user creation, then you should first build the `user` object then call `save` on it.

```
user = User.new(provider: omniauth['provider'], 
   uid: omniauth['uid'], 
   email: omniauth['info']['email'], 
   username: omniauth['info']['nickname'])

# user.save will return a boolean value.
if user.save
  flash.now[:notice] = "Signed in successfully"
  sign_in_and_redirect(:user, user)
else
  ...
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your response -- I've edited the question for clarity but what I'm really wondering is why `#sign_in_and_redirect`is persisting my user at all and, secondly, how that occurs given that the user is invalid.